# Symmetric 2 Dimensional Array

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

What would the code be to test whether an array is two-dimensional?  For one dimension I know that reversing the list will work.  For two-dimensions I know that the opposite row / column must be the same.  In other words [1][2] must equal [2][1] and so forth.

(defun symmetric-check (list) (equal list (reverse list)))

Comment: Array: (setf arr (make-array '(2 2) :initial-contents '((1 2) (2 3))))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your definition of symmetry.

In linear algebra, a matrix is called symmetric iff it is equal to its transpose (this is equivalent to saying that *M[i, j] = M[j, i]* for all *i* and *j*).  Thus,

```
(defun matrix-symmetric-p (m)
  (equal m (transpose-matrix m)))

(defun transpose-matrix (m)
  ;; implement this
  ...)
```

I strongly recommend using actual arrays, though, because it will make doing things like this easier and much more efficient.

```
(defun matrix-symmetric-p (m)
  (loop for i from 0 below (array-dimension m 0)
        always
          (loop for j from 0 below (array-dimension m 1)
                always
                  (= (aref m i j) (aref m j i)))))
```

Comment: For a non-square matrix this code would crash... also you are checking each pair twice. Why using `loop` even when its syntax is actually more verbose than the lispier `dotimes`?

Comment: @6502 True, but the definition of symmetry I used doesn't make sense for a non-square matrix anyway.  `dotimes` would necessitate using something like `block` and `return-from` (note that I used the `always` directive) and would therefore be a bit uglier, semantically.

Comment: I put the "actual array" through the test I needed, and it worked.  Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

First of all implementing a matrix using a list of lists is inefficient if you need random access because that is going to cost `O(n + m)` instead of the cheaper `O(1)` using a bidimensional array.

To check for symmetry the first thing is ensuring that the matrix is square and then you just need to check that element `m_ij` is equal to element `m_ji` for all pairs.

Since you need checking all pairs for symmetry it makes sense to only consider `i > j` to avoid doing each test twice (`>` and not `>=` because clearly `m_ii` is equal to itself).

As an added bonus checking for symmetry doesn't require considering main diagonal elements.

```
(defun symmetric (m)
  (let ((rows (array-dimension m 0))
        (cols (array-dimension m 1)))
    (when (= rows cols)
      (dotimes (i rows T)
        (dotimes (j i)
          (unless (= (aref m i j) (aref m j i))
            (return-from symmetric NIL)))))))

(let ((m (make-array (list 5 5) :initial-element 0)))
  (dotimes (i 5)
    (dotimes (j 5)
      (setf (aref m i j) (* (1+ i) (1+ j)))))
  (print m)
  (print (symmetric m))
  (setf (aref m 3 2) 9)
  (print m)
  (print (symmetric m)))
```

Answer (score 1):

However, the title is vague, given your example, the analogue would probably be this:

```
(defun symmetric-2d-list-p (list)
  (equal (reverse (mapcar #'reverse list)) list))

(symmetric-2d-list-p '((1 1 1) (2 2) (3) (2 2) (1 1 1))) ; T
(symmetric-2d-list-p '((2 1 2) (2 2) (3) (2 2) (2 1 2))) ; T
(symmetric-2d-list-p '((1 1 1) (2 2) (3 4) (2 2) (1 1 1))) ; NIL
```

But you really want to clarify, because 2d arrays are entirely different things, then lists containing lists.

It may certainly be a better answer, the one that doesn't require creation of additional lists. I really did it this way because of your original example. Hopefully someone will post a more optimal version.